# Navigation elements position

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do a navigation bar with some `<ul>`and`<li>` but at this time I can position the elements in the order I want, I am learing how to postion elements and I am new at this css :/ I hope you guys can help me out.

```css
#navbar {
 width:100%;
 height: 75px;
 top : 20px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 999;
 background-color: #fff;
 opacity: 0.8; 
}

.logo img {
 height: 75px;
}

.navigation{
 width: 100%;
 height: 75px;
 top :10px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 999;
}

ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 text-decoration: none;
}
li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left :200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="navbar">
 <div class="logo">
  <img src="img/logo.png">
 </div>
 <div class="navigation">
 <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#aboutus">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contacts">Contacts</a></li>
  <li><a href="#partners">Partners</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

I have this so far but I want something like this
[What I want to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I071.png)

The problem is when I try to style the `li a {` it doesnt let me to make only margin from the  elements besides he give margin from everthing :/

Comment: "The problem is when I try to style the li a { it doesnt let me to make only margin from the elements besides he give margin from everthing :/" - can you reword that? I don't understand. What specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: Have a look here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: @MichaelCoker I tried to give a margin from the div class navigation to make the ul or li like the photo, the problem is when I do this the elements inside <li> are affected and also receive the margin-left and makes the spaces beetween <li> huge

Comment: @SimonaMi I think the navbar I want to do its simple and doesnt need that bootstrap "template"

Comment: You can still have a look at the implementation in Bootstrap and implement it the same way in your code

Comment: @RafaelSousa then use a margin value less than 200px, which is what you have there currently.

Comment: the problem is I want to get the <li> margin from the left of the div class navigation @MichaelCoker I uploaded an image to give an example of what I want

Comment: @RafaelSousa I'm not going to make that whole menu for you. Not sure if that's what you're asking, but SO isn't a code writing service. What part specifically do you need help with? Just creating a margin between the links? If so, like I said, just use a margin that is < the current value of 200px. Maybe like 25px or 30px.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 background: #222;
 font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
}

.container {
 width: 50%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: fixed !important;
  top : 20px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;

}

header::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10%;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.logo img{
 height: 60px;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 60px;
  padding-top: 30px;

  position: relative;
}

nav a {
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

nav a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #444;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0%;

  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

nav a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
      <div class="logo">
      <img src="img/logo.png">
      </div>

    <div class="container">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#aboutus">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contacts">Contacts</a></li>
          <li><a href="#partners">Partners</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for you. I changed only the last two CSS rules, everything else is like in your code.

```css
#navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.logo img {
  height: 75px;
}

.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
li:first-child {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
ul li a {
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="navbar">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="img/logo.png">
  </div>
  <div class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#aboutus">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contacts">Contacts</a></li>
      <li><a href="#partners">Partners</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```